# ReportProgress in BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net

The progress bar is repeated two or three times before completing the operation on my backgroundworker

this code:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'Load Data
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListData.Count
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((i / ListData.Count) * 100)
    Next
    If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    'set datasource of DatagridView
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks

End Sub
```

In my load form

```
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
```

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several mistakes. First, if you intend to display an increasing progress bar, you should use:

```
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
```

in your load form. Next, you are checking `BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` only after going through all your `ListData`. That is too late, you have to check it every iteration of the loop. I also really doubt you want your loop to go from 0 to `ListData.Count`; you probably either want to start at 1 or go to `ListData.Count - 1`. I can't tell from your question. Your loop should look more like this:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To ListData.Count - 1
    If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit For
    Else
        ' You should be doing some work here, not just calling ReportProgress
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * (i+1) / ListData.Count)
    End If
Next
```

Another mistake is calculating `(i / ListData.Count) * 100`; `i` and `ListData.Count` are integers, so their division will always be zero until the end, when it will be 1. Instead, multiply the numerator by 100 to get percentages.

Comment: I assume that the `For` loop should go from `1` to `ListData.Count`; otherwise the first iteration indicates no work was done (`100 * 0 / ListData.Count` equals zero).

Comment: Dour, thanks. mm what style to progressbar put on BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted ??

Comment: Good spotting @Karl, the question is ambiguous. I changed it to go from `0` to `ListData.Count-1`.

Comment: @Wfgo, why do you want to change the style of the `ProgressBar`? I would never do that. What effect are you trying to get?

Comment: @DourHighArch, mm, the style continuos with this code the progressbar complete "35%" (for example).. with the style Marquee to Blocks, the progressbar complete "90%" and this look good.. I do not understand what happen

Comment: @Wfgo, `ProgressBarStyle` has nothing to do with percent complete and you should not be changing it. I can't see your screen, so you have to post what `ListData.Count` is, what you are doing in your loop, and what progress you are seeing to your question.